# JSON response to C/C++ object and C/C++ objects to Java /Objective C

Tags: java, c++, objective-c, c

Is there any way to convert the JSON response to C/C++ object structure and,convert the those object (C/C++) objects back to java or Objective c.

Answer (score 0):

There are tons of libraries for Java side at least; my favorite is [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org), others like [GSON](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) and [flex-json](http://flexjson.sourceforge.net/) also work well. And although many fall for it, I would recommend against using org.json's default lib; it's an old proof-of-concept and is missing most useful things other libs offer.

Note that given that JSON is the interchange format, there need/should not be close coupling between c/c++ libs and java libs; each can and should map data using whatever works best on that platform.